# What is the source of my father's Hebrew name? It is כלאוונא

Tags: names, talmud-gemara

I am going getting a GET from my wife and the Rabbi asked for my father's Hebrew name.  I told him it was כלאוונא, the same as my great-grandfather. The rabbi said he had never heard of the name.  After some research, we found it mentioned in the Talmud without any explanation we could understand.  Can you shed any light on this?  Thanks.

Comment: Mark Cantor, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Where did you see this name in the Talmud? Please [edit] the source into your question; that would make it a great deal easier for people to investigate it.

Comment: It appears in the talmud with a space between the first 2 letters and the last 5 letters. Here are the links where it appears in 2 documents below from halakhah origin of names:http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_8990_163.pdf 
http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_8440_182.pdf

Comment: here is another page, but it doesn't give the talmudic citation http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_8990_121.pdf

Comment: How do you pronounce that name? Shouldn't you give the GET to your wife, not you getting a GET from her?

Comment: The family has always pronounced it Cluvnah

Comment: @RebChaimHaQoton - you are correct

Comment: This question has two close votes for being "off-topic, Hebrew." I don't agree -- it asks for the meaning of a specific Jewish name in the context of Judaism.

Comment: Please [edit] your sources, including as much bibliographical information as you can, into your question.

Comment: Explanatory note to supplement @IsaacMoses' -- it's a good idea to [edit] the gemaras where the name appears as well as its pronunciation into the question, because [1] those are important pieces of information [2] comments are less visible (and they don't last forever), questions do.

Comment: My grandfather came from Gruzdziai, now in Lithuania.  He was a "Cantor" and a Shochet.

Comment: Here is a link to his headstone in Hebrew. http://s15.postimg.org/tg31l1ctn/marker.jpg

Comment: @MarkCantor it looks like the spelling on the headstone is with a 'ח', not a 'כ'.

Answer (score 3):

This appears in the Talmud in [Nazir 7a](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%99%D7%A8_%D7%96_%D7%90). It is a combination of two word, כל meaning all or each and אוונא which means a region or section of land. It appears in a very technical discussion about taking a Nazarite vow which was given a term equivalent to a distance to another location. The term אוונא refers to a standard for measuring land.

From the [discussions](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_8990_121.pdf) in the sefarim you link to (which are about names for a Get) it is not related to that discussion, rather it is a name associated with the Hebrew names of [Lapidus](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15812#showrashi=true&v=4) or [Saadia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saadia_Gaon).

Comment: I am not sure this explains the meaning of the name though.

Comment: It's not about the GET, we have wanted to know more about this Jewish name for some time.  He died before his 9 children had children, so they named the first male of each of his children's children with the name  כלאוונא

Comment: @MarkCantor, My only point was that it is in the context of a Get that such names get attention in Jewish books.

Comment: @Sarge, I couldn't really find much about that, but that part of the question really goes off-topic, IMO. Jewishly, it is the foreign language name that substitutes for one of those two Hebrew names. Why people connected to either of those names, I don't know.

Comment: You may want to remove this answer, as it is based on a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not a common name, even in the Talmud, it is mentioned in [Oholei Shem](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36130&st=&pgnum=178&hilite=) under כלאוונא where he says look at חלוונא. Looking further in Oholei Shem I can not find חלוונא. However in [Kuntras Hasheimos Hachadash - note 13 & 14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8990&st=&pgnum=110&hilite=) he mentions a connection to Lapidus and Saadya.

The name does exist as you can see from this [Lzecher Nishmas](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30496&st=&pgnum=2).

Answer (score 0):

The Aruch Hashulchan In Even Haezer 129 which discusses the names and spellings has this name by the letter ח and he goes through the spelling,and the name itself.

Comment: Im not sure what "*he goes through the spelling,and the name itself*" means.

Comment: The Aruch Hashulchan does that for all names in the section of names regarding gitten,he goes through the correct spelling.